# How should i apply the intermediate value property to this function

Tags: calculus

I am given the derivative of the function $f(x)=x^2-1$ which is $f'(x)=2x$ and was told to use the intermediate value property of $f'(x)$ to show $f$ has at least one extremum on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Since the function $f'(x)=2x$ is just a line, how am I able to show that there is an extrema?

Comment: What does the intermediate value theorem say?  What are $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$? What are $f'(-1)$ and $f'(1)$

Comment: It is $f$ that has the local extremum, not $f'$. So how do we check for local etrema normally?

Comment: I don't see how the IVP helps here; of course $f'(c)=0$ doesn't, in general, insure that $f$ has an extrema at $c$.

Comment: You can actually do it on $f(x)$ itself, since $f(-1)=f(1)$ and $f(x)$ is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f'(-1)=-2$ and $f'(1)=2.$ The intermediate value property of $f'$ gives some $t \in (-1,1)$ such that $f'(t)=0.$

Answer (score 0):

You use the fact that the equation $f'(x)=0$ has a solution in $[-1,1]$.